# Some git repos don't work with yocto/bitbake

Tags: git, proxy, yocto, bitbake

Yocto gives an error when fetching :

```
ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/robclark/libdri2.git;protocol=http;branch=master'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/pi20/poky/olimex/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libdri2/1_1.0.0+gitAUTOINC+4f1eef3183-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.20462
ERROR: Task 3562 (/home/user/poky/meta-sunxi/recipes-graphics/xorg-xserver/libdri2_git.bb, do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/home/user/poky/olimex/downloads/git2/github.com.ssvb.xf86-video-fbturbo.git'...
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The repo `git://github.com/robclark/libdri2.git;protocol=http;branch=master` works well when not used with yocto.
It's maybe [this bug](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-July/020450.html), so I have tried to apply [the patch](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-July/020451.html) by modifying by hand `bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py b/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, could you get us some more info? Logs, configuration etc? I just tried to pull the libdri2_git.bb [1] into a poky tree, both from mid-December, and as of today, without any issue at all when it comes to fetching the repo. [1] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ebutera/meta-sunxi/master/recipes-graphics/xorg-xserver/libdri2_git.bb

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a workaround pretty much hiddeous, but at least it worked. I've edited the file `poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py` at the line 96 to force the use of http instead of git.

Comment: You're already specifying protocol=http, so don't do this. Look at the log to try and get an understanding of what goes wrong. (It'll show you the exact commands being run).